# Как заполнить пространство точками?

Tags: html, css

[image]

Здесь от отзыва до +1 пространство заполняется точками. Как такое можно сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это реализировано средствами CSS, а именно повторением рисунка точки по горизонтали в нижней части блока.

```
background: url('images/dot.gif') repeat-x bottom;
```

Comment: А блок соотвественно изменяет свой размер в зависимости от размера блока слева и справа?

Comment: Вопрос мне не ясен.

Comment: Пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Можно чистым css:

```
border-bottom: 1px dotted #CCC;
```